# How to determine how many `NavigationSplitView` columns are visible?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

## Overview

- I am using `NavigationSplitView` and the number of columns visible could vary based on the device (macOS, iPhone, iPad) and whether it is using split screen (iPad can run 2 apps at the same time).

## Questions

1. In `NavigationSplitView` how to determine how many columns are visible?
2. Or how to determine if a view was pushed or not?
3. Or was the view a slide over (iPad sidebar slides over)?

## Background

Reason for asking: I have a sidebarList, contentList and detailList. Now I would like to have different selection of cells depending on how many columns are visible

## Sample Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var departments = ["D1"]
    @State private var employees = ["E1", "E2", "E3"]
    @State private var selectedDepartment: String?
    @State private var selectedEmployee: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(departments, id: \.self, selection: $selectedDepartment) { department in
                Text(department)
            }
        } content: {
            List(employees, id: \.self, selection: $selectedEmployee) { employee in
                Text(employee)
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selectedEmployee {
                Text(selectedEmployee)
            } else {
                Text("No employee selected")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NavigationSplitViewVisibility structure in the initialiser.

```
@State private var columnVisibilty: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
```

This would be the example for an 3 column design. By reading or changing the state variable you are able to control it. (Therefore the binding, the system sets what it currently is displaying) added for clarity

```
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibilty) sidebar: {
...
} content: {
...
} detail: {
...
}
```

Here is the link to Apples docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitviewvisibility

Added the crude example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            Text("Sidebar:")
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Print") {
                        print(columnVisibility)
                    }
                }
        } content: {
            Text("Content:")
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Print") {
                        print(columnVisibility)
                    }
                }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail:")
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Print") {
                        print(columnVisibility)
                    }
                }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This lets me set an initial setting BUT it gets updated with the current status of the SplitView. Just press print button and you can see the changes.

Comment: This doesn't tell you exactly how many columns are being displayed. For example on iPad you could have multiple apps open side by side, thought you might have requested for `.all` it doesn't guarantee that all are displayed. I would like to currently how many are being displayed.

Comment: Yes it does. Therefore it is a binding. The value gets updated by the system. At least it was at my test. Posted Source above, and there it worked just fine. And yes you may wish something that the system will not do, but reading the value after that, shows you what the system did

Comment: You are spot on, edit your answer to include your comment so that it would benefit others. I didn't know the value changed

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, clarified it with the Binding. The SwiftUI docs are catastrophic. But if there is a binding then there is mostly an update of the current value, so it is worth reading it out at some place (and not getting to frustrated if it is not what you hoped for :) )

Comment: I agree, after you stated it, it seems obvious, but I didn't realise that earlier, I kept thinking it was a preference value set by the developers thanks once again! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Agreed reading documentation is the best thoroughly ... sometimes there is so much or so less :D, I will be more thorough .. thanks!

Comment: I still think it was a valid question and especially the part what do I get back in a binding is not clearly stated in most of Apples documentation... and therefore might change over time. This makes it sometimes quite annoying. So, glad to help

Comment: On iPhone, SwiftUI doesn't change the value I set, it remains `.all`, Ideally it should have been `.detailOnly`. Not sure if this is a bug

Comment: I check it out tonight. .all should definitely be a bug

Comment: You are right, the view collapses as expected to a single view, but the value will not update accordingly. The value should at least reflect that behaviour...

Comment: Yeah I have filed a feedback, hope it gets fixed